# How can I light emission per vertex and per vertex lighting in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

I want to see a chart with color specified per vertex and to get little bit of shading too. 
But if I use `MeshBasicMaterial` I only get VertexColor with no dynamic shading. 
On the other hand, if I use `MeshPhongMaterial` I just get shading but without emissiveness from my vertex colors.

Comment: Look at this example http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I reviewd and try it but I am using BufferGeometry and it seems like createMultiMaterialObject is only working with Geometry.  I was trying to skip writing a shader, but it seems like I cant escape of that.

Answer (score 0):

As the THREE.JS PhongMaterial supports `vertexColors`, giving you a nice combination of dynamic lighting and vertex colors, I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Perhaps that is something you should investigate more?

However, as an alternative to writing a custom shader you could try rendering your model in multiple passes.

This will not give you as much control over the way the vertex colors and phong lighting are combined as a shader would, but often a simple add/multiply blend can give pretty decent results.

Algorithm:

```
- create two meshes for the BufferGeometry, one with the BasicMaterial and one with the PhongMaterial
- for the PhongMaterial, set
    depthFunc = THREE.EqualDepth
    transparent = true;
    blending = THREE.AdditiveBlending(or MultiplyBlending)
- render the first mesh
- render the second mesh at the exact same spot
```